# eliminate word in the String using regex java

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to know how can I eliminate and remove the word in the string using Java.
example :

```
String a="hello world";
System.out.println("my test"+a);
JButton button=new JButton("button");
Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(a).group();
```

result 1

```
String a=;
System.out.println(+a);
JButton button=new JButton();
Pattern.compile().matcher(a).group();
```

result 2

```
String a=              ;
System.out.println(         +a);
JButton button=new JButton(        );
Pattern.compile(      ).matcher(a).group();
```

Comment: i just want to matching and remove word contained character (")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
String ascii=Character.toString((char)34);
Pattern.compile(ascii+".*"+ascii);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the .replaceAll() method

```
String s = a.replaceAll("\\w+", "");
```

that will replace all instances of the regex with a blank string.

Comment: i want to remove word contained in character (")

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure what you want, but assuming that your sample data is your code, then you can use this regex:

```
".*?"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ0yL0/1)**

[image]

Comment: how do i implement on java ??? it cannot using char (")